# awk and newlines in the input data

Tags: shell, awk

I want to find files in a directory and identify by their mimetype, **not** by the extension of the files.

I'am using this command to determine the mime type:

```
% find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} file --mime-type {}
./foo
bar.png: image/png
./OWoHp.png: image/png
./J7ZwV.png: image/png
./foo.txt: inode/x-empty
./bar: inode/x-empty
./hUXnc.png: image/png
```

The first file has a newline in the filename:

```
% ls foo$'\n'bar.png
foo?bar.png
```

That's ok and the file should **not** be renamed.

With the next command I want to filter all files that are not images.

```
% find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} file --mime-type {} | awk -F$"\0" -F": " '/image/ {print $1}'
bar.png
./OWoHp.png
./J7ZwV.png
./hUXnc.png
```

and identify their sizes:

```
% find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} file --mime-type {} | awk -F$"\0" -F":" '/image/ {print $1}' | xargs -I{} identify -format "%[fx:w*h] %i\n" {}
identify: unable to open image `bar.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2709.
identify: unable to open file `bar.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3922.
26696 ./OWoHp.png
47275 ./J7ZwV.png
37975 ./hUXnc.png
```

But that does not work because there is no file with the name `bar.png`. The correct name is

```
./foo
bar.png
```

with a newline in the name.

Comment: Your main issue here, I think, is that `file` does not preserve the null terminators. It has a `--print0` (or `-0`) option of its own, however that places a null character after the *name*, rather than at the end of each `name: mimetype` output line. So whatever you do, `awk` will see newline separated records.

Comment: @don_crissti I disagree renaming the question, I think it's about the quoting issue, and handling images is just an example.

Comment: @don_crissti Hmm... focussing not on the question title, but the first line, I do understand it is an XY problem indeed. So I do not agree to disagree ;) I rather plead neutral and claim the question is inconsistent. As far as I can see, editing to make one of first line and title match the other would both break something, so we leave it at that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `-exec sh -c '...'` construct with `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'file --brief --mime-type "$0" | \
grep -q ^image/ && identify -format "%[fx:w*h] %i\n" "$0"' {} \;
```

or with `exiftool`:

```
exiftool -q -if '$mimetype =~ /image/' -p '$megapixels $directory/$filename' -r .
```

Comment: The `exiftool` gives a `Warning: [Minor] Tag 'megapixels' not defined - ./hUXnc.png` ;)

Comment: @A.B. - that means `megapixels` tag is missing (odd, as it's a composite tag derived from `imagesize`, does it print the size if you run `exiftool -p '$imagesize' hUXnc.png` ?); you could add `-f` to the command so that instead of that message a dash is printed for any missing tag but that's not the expected result...

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet will be to use a shell loop instead of xargs: Then you can control how commands are sent the filename argument.

```
find . -type f -print0 | 
while IFS= read -rd "" filename; do
    type=$( file --brief "$filename" )
    if [[ $type == *image* ]]; then
        identify -format "%[fx:w*h] %i\n" "$filename"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

As steeldriver pointed out, your problem is not `awk`, it's `file`. There is no NUL in the input you are giving to `awk` because `file` ate it. I would do this whole thing in the shell instead:

```
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do 
    file --mime-type "$file" | grep -qP "\bimage/" && 
        printf '%s %s\0' $(identify -format '%[fx:w*h]' "$file") "$file";
done | sort -gz | tr '\0' '\n'
256 ./file 10
256 ./file 15
484 ./file 16
576 ./file 11
576 ./file 17
1024 ./file 12
1024 ./file 19
2304 ./file 13
5625 ./file 14
15190 ./file 2
15680 ./file 1
16384 ./file 9
65536 ./file 18
145200 ./file 0
183531 ./file 6
364807 ./file
3
364807 ./file 4
364807 ./file 5
388245 ./file 8
550560 ./file 7
```

I included `sort` since I assume you're trying to improve your answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/641650/85695). The example above was run on file names with spaces and one (`file\n3` with a newline). For some reason, `identify` won't print `\0`-terminated lines so I used `printf` instead.